# Как получить нормальную ссылку, если путь получен из переменной или из списка? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```
import docx
import os

d = os.path.abspath('E:\Mr.Ip\Desktop\Учеба\Урок\Folder\1 от 09.01.2020\01 needed file.docx')

print(d)

>>> E:\Mr.Ip\Desktop\Учеба\Урок\Folder от 09.01.2020 needed file.docx
```

Добавляем r перед путем:

```
import docx
import os

d = os.path.abspath(r'E:\Mr.Ip\Desktop\Учеба\Урок\Folder\1 от 09.01.2020\01 needed file.docx')

print(d)

>>>E:\Mr.Ip\Desktop\Учеба\Урок\Folder\1 от 09.01.2020\01 needed file.docx
```

Получаем нормальную ссылку на файл.

Вопрос: как получить нормальную ссылку, если путь получен из переменной или из списка?

```
import docx
import os

t = 'E:\Profile\Desktop\Учеба\Урок\Folder\1 от 09.01.2020\01 needed file.docx'

d = os.path.abspath(t)

print(d)

>>> E:\Profile\Desktop\Учеба\Урок\Folder от 09.01.2020 needed file.docx
```

Получаем непонятные символы после Folder вместо "\"

Полный код выглядит так:

```
import xlsxwriter
import os
import fnmatch

directory_transit = []
file_names = []
pattern = '*needed*.docx'
path = r'.'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    directory_transit.append(dirs)
    file_names += (fnmatch.filter(files, pattern))

print(file_names)
directory = directory_transit[1]
directory.sort()
print(directory)
```

Получаем 2 списка. В 1 название needed файла, во 2 папка в которой он лежит.

```
>>>['1 needed.docx', '01 Neededed.docx', '01 Needed file for examlpe.docx']
['1 от 09.01.2020', '6 от 14.02.2020', '8 от 14.02.2020']
```

Но при проверке, например os.path.isfile(file_names[0]), выдает false, так же с папками.  Что не так не пойму (

Comment: Проблема в том, что путь в переменной изначально неправильный. Обратный слеш и буква после него — это один специальный символ (по аналогии с `\n`). Чтобы это изменить, обратный слеш нужно экранировать таким же слешем. Модификатор строки `r` делает это автоматически. Непонятно, как ответить на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Можно ли прописать как-то чтобы "\" экранировался в переменной?

Comment: Почему Вы акцентируете внимание на переменной? Она тут не при чём, дело в строке. Я не понимаю, что мешает Вам сделать так: `t = r'E:\Profile\Desktop\Учеба\Урок\Folder\1 от 09.01.2020\01 needed file.docx'`. Если хотите, можно экранировать все символы руками: `t = 'E:\\Profile\\Desktop\\Учеба\\Урок\\Folder\\1 от 09.01.2020\\01 needed file.docx'`.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня есть очень много папок типа "1 от 09.01.2020" и в них лежит "needed file.docx". Я формирую список таких файлов, и хочу при необходимости иметь доступ к каждому из них. Например, по условию вытащить из каждого определенный текст. Хотя, возможно, я как то неправильно ищу файлб и заношу его путь в список. Надо проверить.

Comment: Тогда приведите, пожалуйста, в вопрос код, который формирует этот список. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Собирайте полный путь функцией `os.path.join()`, тогда всё будет правильно и не придется ломать голову.

> при проверке, например os.path.file(file_names[0]), выдает false, так
>   же с папками.

Потому что это не полный путь, а путь в текущей папке, а в папке, в которой выполняется скрипт (обычно это типа папка, где скрипт лежит), где в таком случае выполняется поиск, такого файла нет.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Собрал!)